# Touch coords and OpenGL space coords

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm having a hard time implementing the rotation and movement of an on-screen OpenGL shape. Basically, what I want to achieve is being able to control the shape using a touch screen. **Wherever I touch, it should rotate to that direction and start moving towards until it gets there.**

Here's the code that sets up the frustum and the camera in `onSurfaceChanged()`:

```
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float sizeRatio = (float) width / height;

    Matrix.frustumM(
            projectionMatrix, 0, -sizeRatio, sizeRatio, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 20.0f
    );
    Matrix.setLookAtM(
            viewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -60, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    );
    Matrix.multiplyMM(globalMvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
```

and here's how the touch input is handled in `onTouchEvent()` (`shape` is an object that stores position and rotation and then draws the shape on the screen):

```
        lastTouchX = event.getX();
        lastTouchY = event.getY();

        float shapePosX = shape.getPositionX();
        float shapePosY = shape.getPositionY();

        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport, 0);

        float[] unprojectedTouchCoords = new float[4];
        GLU.gluUnProject(
                lastTouchX, lastTouchY, 0,
                viewMatrix, 0,
                projectionMatrix, 0,
                viewport, 0,
                unprojectedTouchCoords, 0
        );
        float unprojectedX = unprojectedTouchCoords[0] / unprojectedTouchCoords[3];
        float unprojectedY = unprojectedTouchCoords[1] / unprojectedTouchCoords[3];
        float rotation = 90 - (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(
                shapePosY - unprojectedY, shapePosX - unprojectedX
        ));

        shape.setRotation(rotation);

        float moveX = 2 * (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation));
        float moveY = 2 * (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation));

        shape.move(moveX, moveY);
```

However, it doesn't seem to work well. The shape is moving in the wrong direction, and the rotation is only correct if the position of the shape is (0, 0). In any other case, it breaks.

I guess this problem involves distance between the camera and the shape in the OpenGL space, but I have no idea where and how to fix that. I tried bringing the camera closer to the shape but with no apparent improvement.

Can you please help me with this one? I'm getting really frustrated.

Comment: Come on, guys. This musn't be that difficult. A lot of games use this kind of touch contol, so there must be someone that knows how to do it right :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked deeply at your code but I really want to give you a suggestion: **the order of transformations matters in OpenGL, because they are cumulative**. 
This means that *`rotate and translate`* is different than *`translate and rotate`*.

[**Here**](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring08/cps124/notes/04_pipeline/cox_04transformations.pdf) is a good starting point to understand what I'm saying.

Comment: Thanks, I've already took it into account and made it the correct order (I know it's correct because all of the three - translation, rotation and scaling - are correct). The problem here is that unprojected coords are wrong and in turn the calculated angle between the touch location and location of the shape too (checked the console output).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have co-ordinates calculation problem. You need to `@Override` the `onTouchEvent` method of `GLSurfaceView`, rest is below

```
private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;
private float mPreviousX;
private float mPreviousY;

 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
        // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
        // interested in events where the touch position changed.

        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                float dx = x - mPreviousX;
                float dy = y - mPreviousY;

                // reverse direction of rotation above the mid-line
                if (y > getHeight() / 2) {
                    dx = dx * -1 ;
                }

                // reverse direction of rotation to left of the mid-line
                if (x < getWidth() / 2) {
                    dy = dy * -1 ;
                }

                mRenderer.setAngle(
                        mRenderer.getAngle() +
                        ((dx + dy) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR));  // = 180.0f / 320
                requestRender();
        }

        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What is mRenderer? What does requestRender() do? The code you provided does not relate to any of my problems. I know you tried but I guess I'll be left without a solution :(

Comment: `mRenderer` is a class instance of `MyGLRenderer` which implements `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`, I was assuming you are implementing surface view to show your graphics and I hope you have one...

Comment: Of course I have. How would I render anything without a renderer and a surface view? I have a problem with **angle calculation**, not API implementation.